Identify 64k x 8 bit DRAM in DIP-24N from the pinout
Unfortunately, I don't have the photo of the IC or any reference to it. All I have is a high-resolution photo of a PCB with unpopulated footprint where this IC should fit. It is wired in parallel to a couple of 4464 DRAM chips (64k x 4 bit DRAM: datasheet), so I guessed the pinout and figured out that it should be a 64k x 8 bit DRAM to be used if 4464 footprints are not populated. From the dimension I figured out that this IC should be packaged in DIP-24N. I couldn't find any reference to such a part online.
I am fairly confident in the pinout that I have deducted from the board layout by tracing the connections to other DRAM footprints. Since there's no silkscreen on the board, it's impossible to tell the correct orientation, so the pin numbering might need to be rotated (pin 1 -> pin 13, pin 24 -> pin 12), but most likely not flipped (all other components are on the top side of the board). Here is what I came up with:
     +----------+
 GND |1       24| GND
  NC |2       23| D7
  D0 |3       22| D6
  D1 |4       21| D5
  D2 |5       20| D4
  D3 |6       19| !CAS
 !WE |7       18| A5
!RAS |8       17| A3
  A0 |9       16| A4
  A2 |10      15| A5
  A1 |11      14| A7
 VCC |12      13| VCC
     +----------+

Here is the cropped image of the footprint coming from a full photo of a PCB:

The source of the photo is VGA Legacy MKIII, it contains full resolution photos of the PCB from both sides, as well as couple of other photos of similar boards (the board is MDC-V3, the DIP-24N is the top left corner if looking from the component side).

Are you sure it is a missing component? Here for example on the left the two components are diffrent (QFN instead of DFN in yours). So it might be a shared PCB for several versions? https://a.allegroimg.com/s1024/0c1de0/f9d7775d47148490c028064f3c42

The site doesn't come up very quickly for me and times out, so forget looking at it for now. But one of the problems with CGA/EGA before VGA was the lack of dual port DRAM. I believe (my memory is... uncertain) that the VGA used dual-port. There also needed to be code (in a ROM) so that it could validate itself and start up properly during boot (the BIOS knew how to look for that code.) I've no idea if this is an old ROM location that someone wanted to desolder or if dual-port DRAM was used on this board. But if my memory is worth much anymore, you might look for 24 pin dual port DRAM chips.

On the other hand, I might just assume that you've identified the pins correctly going to that location (no reason to doubt you.) If so, it isn't ROM for boot. And it doesn't look dual-port to me, either (which is the only reason I'm doubting, at all.) With CGA and EGA we had to be very careful when and how writing to memory (monitored horizontal and vertical retrace signals in software to do it) to avoid "tearing." VGA got rid of that problem, memory serving. But by using dual-port (like Fujitsu MB81461, which is DIP-24 by the way.) So I'm at a loss for you, right now.

This board comes assembled in two variants: with two 4464 in DIP-18 or with two 4464 in PLCC-18. So my assumption is that there should've been a third variant with just one chip in DIP-24 which can replace both 4464. I might be wrong and this space is reserved for a connector, so the memory chips can be installed on a daughter board.
